# Weird behavior of fopen on ios

Tags: objective-c, c, ios

I am trying to create a file by fopen and then write it, but weird things happened.

1. When I plug in the iphone to the usb port. Everything works fine. A file is created at the tmp directory or the document directory as expected.
2. When I plug off the device and do the same thing, the file did not appear. I was wondering why.

I use fopen to create the file. In my case, I should do this to create and then write the file. The call is fopen(pcm_output, "wb+");

Comment: Is this code for ios or the native system being plugged into?

Comment: I think so. Or it would not work even it is plugged into

Comment: I also got this "Mar 17 21:42:45 unknown CommCenter[23] <Notice>: MessageCenterModel is telling PDP context -1 to go active.
Mar 17 21:42:45 unknown sandboxd[3933] <Notice>: ZhiJia_Listen(3916) deny file-write-create /�6 "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use this call.

```
    char const *path = [fileManager fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:url.path];
```

From the docs...

fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:
- (const char *)fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:(NSString *)path

iOS (2.0 and later)

Returns a C-string representation of a given path that properly encodes Unicode strings for use by the file system.

path: A string object containing a path to a file.
A C-string representation of path that properly encodes Unicode strings for use by the file system.

Comment: Thanks, it works. And I was wondering why this method work and why the NSUTF8StringEncoding does not work.

Comment: That will create a proper encoding, but remember, the file system does not like just any characters.  That's why they have a special method to generate the char* version for the file system.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably writing outside of the sandbox, can you post the path?
Just as a test try to turn on iTunes Sharing (this should have no effect, it's just a test) for your app.

**EDIT:**

After testing I discovered that you have to use:

```
NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithCString:pcm_output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
fopen([filePath UTF8String], "wb+");
```

Instead of just:

```
fopen([filePath UTF8String], "wb+");
```

Comment: Hello, I had write the file under this path "/var/mobile/Applications/ED98116B-BD1E-4319-B473-A699DB6B9F86/Documents
" I believe it is inside the sandbox. I will try out your method anyway.

Comment: Thanks @fbernardo, but it's not working. I was wondering if it is related to jail break.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                 NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES
                                                 ); 
NSString* docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
_tempLogPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Aisound5_CBLog.log"];
_tempPcmPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"OutPcm.pcm"];
_tempWavPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"OutWav.wav"];


tts_resource = [[bundle pathForResource:@"Resource_dev" ofType:@"irf"] UTF8String];
tts_log = [_tempLogPath UTF8String];
pcm_output = [_tempPcmPath UTF8String];
wav_output = [_tempWavPath UTF8String];
```

The original code is this, in which tts_resource tts_log pcm_output and wav_output are defined in a .h file and used in a .c file with fopen.

I had tried in your way to init the const string with the explicit const char* style, but the problem remains the same.