# Using .irf file as sound resource for tts (text-to-speech) engine on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, text-to-speech

Can't really find any info about `irf` files and tts (text-to-speech) anywhere, let alone to do with iOS.

Although according to some Chinese websites it seems to be used a lot for GPS "audio" on Android applications.

So...any ideas on how to use an irf file as the audio database for tts on iOS?

[Sample IRF File](http://pan.baidu.com/wap/shareview?&shareid=3654102366&uk=3825542120&dir=%2Fautonavidata60&page=1&num=20&fsid=891585242533676&third=0)

———————————————————————————————————————————

edit:

[github](https://github.com/onyx-intl/booxsdk/tree/master/code/src/tts/aisound) has a post `booxsdk/code/src/tts/aisound/` which contains C and C++ files on how to their:

[Sample IRF File](https://github.com/onyx-intl/booxsdk/blob/master/code/src/tts/aisound/resource.irf)

this should be a big clue on how to get it working on iOS, for someone with bigger brains than I.

———————————————————————————————————————————

edit 2:

Sample C Code:

**ivTTSStandardAPISample.c**

```
// ivTTSStandardAPISample.c : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ivTTS.h"

/* constant for TTS heap size */
//#define ivTTS_HEAP_SIZE       38000 /* ahh */
#define ivTTS_HEAP_SIZE     58000 /* ohh */

/* constant for cache allocation */
#define ivTTS_CACHE_SIZE    512
#define ivTTS_CACHE_COUNT   1024
#define ivTTS_CACHE_EXT     8

/* Message */
ivTTSErrID DoMessage()
{
/* do stuff */
if(1)
{
    /* tts me up */
    return ivTTS_ERR_OK;
}
else
{
    /* exit */
    return ivTTS_ERR_EXIT;
}
}

FILE *fpOutput = 0;
/* output callback */
ivTTSErrID OnOutput(
    ivUInt16        nCode,          /* [in] output data code */
    ivCPointer      pcData,         /* [in] output data buffer */
    ivSize          nSize )         /* [in] output data size */
{
/* play */
/* something */
fwrite(pcData, 1, nSize, fpOutput);
return ivTTS_ERR_OK;
}

/* read resource callback */
void ivCall ReadResCB(
    ivPointer       pParameter,     /* [in] user callback parameter */
    ivPointer       pBuffer,        /* [out] read resource buffer */
    ivResAddress    iPos,           /* [in] read start position */
    ivResSize       nSize )         /* [in] read size */
{
FILE* pFile = (FILE*)pParameter;
fseek(pFile, iPos, SEEK_SET);
fread(pBuffer, nSize, 1, pFile);
}

/* output callback */
ivTTSErrID ivCall OutputCB(
    ivPointer       pParameter,     /* [in] user callback parameter */
    ivUInt16        nCode,          /* [in] output data code */
    ivCPointer      pcData,         /* [in] output data buffer */
    ivSize          nSize )         /* [in] output data size */
{
/* tts ma? */
ivTTSErrID tErr = DoMessage();
if ( tErr != ivTTS_ERR_OK ) return tErr;
/* play tts */
return OnOutput(nCode, pcData, nSize);
}

int main(void)
{
ivHTTS          hTTS;
ivPByte         pHeap;
ivTResPackDesc  tResPackDesc;
ivTTSErrID      ivReturn;

if (1)
{
    /* heap size */
    pHeap = (ivPByte)malloc(ivTTS_HEAP_SIZE);
    memset(pHeap, 0, ivTTS_HEAP_SIZE);
    fpOutput = fopen("OutPcm.pcm","wb+");
    if( !fpOutput )
        return 0;

    /* initalizing */
    /* can multipackage */
    tResPackDesc.pCBParam = fopen("..\\..\\Resource\\Resource.irf", "rb");
    tResPackDesc.pfnRead = ReadResCB;
    tResPackDesc.pfnMap = NULL;
    tResPackDesc.nSize = 0;

    if (tResPackDesc.pCBParam)
    {
        tResPackDesc.pCacheBlockIndex = (ivPUInt8)malloc(ivTTS_CACHE_COUNT + ivTTS_CACHE_EXT);
        tResPackDesc.pCacheBuffer = (ivPUInt8)malloc((ivTTS_CACHE_COUNT + ivTTS_CACHE_EXT)*(ivTTS_CACHE_SIZE));
        tResPackDesc.nCacheBlockSize = ivTTS_CACHE_SIZE;
        tResPackDesc.nCacheBlockCount = ivTTS_CACHE_COUNT;
        tResPackDesc.nCacheBlockExt = ivTTS_CACHE_EXT;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /* TTS create */
    ivReturn = ivTTS_Create(&hTTS, (ivPointer)pHeap, ivTTS_HEAP_SIZE, ivNull, (ivPResPackDesc)&tResPackDesc, (ivSize)1);

    /* callback */
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_OUTPUT_CALLBACK, (ivUInt32)OutputCB);

    /* codepage */
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_INPUT_CODEPAGE, ivTTS_CODEPAGE_GBK);

    /* language */
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_LANGUAGE, ivTTS_LANGUAGE_CHINESE);  

    /* volume */
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_VOLUME, ivTTS_VOLUME_NORMAL);

    /************************************************************************
        tts
    ************************************************************************/
    /* speaker XIAOYAN */
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_ROLE, ivTTS_ROLE_XIAOYAN);
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SynthText(hTTS, ivText("你好，这里是科大讯飞语音合成系统。"), -1);
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SynthText(hTTS, ivText("Hello, this is iFLYTEK TTS system."), -1);
    /* speaker TERRY */
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_ROLE, ivTTS_ROLE_TERRY);
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_LANGUAGE, ivTTS_LANGUAGE_ENGLISH);
    ivReturn = ivTTS_SynthText(hTTS, ivText("Hello, this is iFLYTEK TTS system."), -1);

    /* anti-initializing */
    ivReturn = ivTTS_Destroy(hTTS);

    if ( tResPackDesc.pCacheBlockIndex )
    {
        free(tResPackDesc.pCacheBlockIndex);
    }
    if ( tResPackDesc.pCacheBuffer )
    {
        free(tResPackDesc.pCacheBuffer);
    }
    if ( pHeap )
    {
        free(pHeap);
    }
}
fclose(tResPackDesc.pCBParam);
fclose(fpOutput);   
return 0;
}
```

———————————————————————————————————————————

edit 3:

This keeps showing up in my searches:

> AiSound 4 Kernel API

Here's a CPP file:

```
#include "yx_common.h"

pthread_t g_pthreadTTS;

int g_Handle = -1;
char *g_MappedMem = (char *)MAP_FAILED;

/* read resource callback */
ivBool ivCall ReadResCB(ivPointer pParameter, ivPointer pBuffer, ivResAddress iPos, ivResSize nSize )
{
memcpy(pBuffer, g_MappedMem+iPos, nSize);
return ivTrue;
}

ivTTSErrID ivCall OutputCB(ivPointer pParameter, ivUInt16 nCode, ivCPointer pcData, ivSize nSize )
{
/*  */
WriteBuf(0, (BYTE *)pcData, nSize, 'T');
return ivTTS_ERR_OK;
}

ivTTSErrID ivCall ParamChangeCB(ivPointer pParameter, ivUInt32 nParamID, ivUInt32 nParamValue )
{
return ivTTS_ERR_OK;
}

ivTTSErrID ivCall ProgressCB(ivPointer pParameter, ivUInt32 iProcPos, ivUInt32 nProcLen )
{
return ivTTS_ERR_OK;
}

int InitTTS()
{
g_Handle = open("/lib/Resource.irf", O_RDONLY);
if( g_Handle==-1 ) goto ERROR;

g_MappedMem = (char *)mmap(NULL, RESOUSE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, g_Handle, 0);
if( g_MappedMem==MAP_FAILED ) goto ERROR;

return 0;

ERROR:
PRTMSG(MSG_ERR, "init tts error\n");
close(g_Handle);
return -1;
}

int ReleaseTTS()
{
munmap(g_MappedMem, RESOUSE_SIZE);
close(g_Handle);

g_Handle = -1;
g_MappedMem = (char *)MAP_FAILED;
}

void MakeTTS(char* v_pText)
{
ivHTTS  hTTS;
ivPByte pHeap;
ivTTSErrID  ivReturn;

/* */
pHeap = (ivPByte)malloc(ivTTS_HEAP_SIZE);
memset(pHeap, 0, ivTTS_HEAP_SIZE);

/* */
ivTResPackDescExt tResPackDesc;
tResPackDesc.pCBParam = NULL;
tResPackDesc.pfnRead = ReadResCB;
tResPackDesc.pfnMap = NULL;
tResPackDesc.nSize = 0;

tResPackDesc.pCacheBlockIndex = NULL;
tResPackDesc.pCacheBuffer = NULL;
tResPackDesc.nCacheBlockSize = 0;
tResPackDesc.nCacheBlockCount = 0;
tResPackDesc.nCacheBlockExt = 0;

/* */
ivReturn = ivTTS_Create(&hTTS, (ivPointer)pHeap, ivTTS_HEAP_SIZE, ivNull, (ivPResPackDescExt)&tResPackDesc, (ivSize)1, NULL);
ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_OUTPUT_CALLBACK, (ivUInt32)OutputCB);/*  */
ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_PARAMCH_CALLBACK, (ivUInt32)ParamChangeCB);/*  */
ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_PROGRESS_CALLBACK, (ivUInt32)ProgressCB);/*  */
ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_INPUT_CODEPAGE, ivTTS_CODEPAGE_GBK);/*  */
ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_LANGUAGE, ivTTS_LANGUAGE_CHINESE);  /* */
ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_VOLUME, ivTTS_VOLUME_NORMAL);/* */
ivReturn = ivTTS_SetParam(hTTS, ivTTS_PARAM_ROLE, ivTTS_ROLE_XIAOFENG);/* XIAOFENG */
ivReturn = ivTTS_SynthText(hTTS, ivText(v_pText), MAX_UNSIGNED_32);/* */

/*  */
ivReturn = ivTTS_Destroy(hTTS);

if( tResPackDesc.pCacheBlockIndex )
    free(tResPackDesc.pCacheBlockIndex);

if( tResPackDesc.pCacheBuffer )
    free(tResPackDesc.pCacheBuffer);

if( pHeap )
    free(pHeap);
}

void *PlayTTS(void *arg)
{
pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);

int iRet;

IOSET( IOS_TRUMPPOW, IO_TRUMPPOW_ON );//
IOSET( IOS_EARPHONESEL, IO_EARPHONESEL_OFF );//
IOSET( IOS_AUDIOSEL, IO_AUDIOSEL_PC );//

msleep(200);

#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M
BYTE TBuf[960] = {0};
ADEC_CHN iAdecChn = -1;
AUDIO_RAWDATA_S objAudioRawData = {AUDIO_BIT_WIDTH_16, AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_8, 0, 0, (short *)TBuf, (uint)sizeof(TBuf)};

if( !g_objCtrlStart.APlayback[0] )
{
    iRet = HI_ADEC_CreateCH(0, AUDIO_CODEC_FORMAT_ADPCM , HI_TRUE , &iAdecChn); 
    if(iRet)
    {
        PRTMSG(MSG_ERR, "create audio playback chn1 failed: %08x\n", iRet);
        goto TTS_PLAY_STOP;
    }

    iRet = HI_ADEC_StartCH(iAdecChn, 0); 
    if(iRet) 
    {
        PRTMSG(MSG_ERR, "start audio playback chn1 failed: %08x\n", iRet);
        goto TTS_PLAY_STOP;
    }
}
else
{
    g_objPlaybackCtrl.APause = TRUE;// 
}
#endif

#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_V8 || VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M2
BYTE TBuf[960] = {0};
AUDIO_FRAME_S objAudioRawData;
objAudioRawData.enBitwidth = AUDIO_BIT_WIDTH_16;
objAudioRawData.enSoundmode = AUDIO_SOUND_MODE_MOMO;
objAudioRawData.u64TimeStamp = 0;
objAudioRawData.u32Seq = 0;
objAudioRawData.u32Len = sizeof(TBuf);

if( !g_objCtrlStart.APlayback[0] )
{
    SwitchAo(AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_8000);

    ADEC_ATTR_ADPCM_S objAdpcmAttr;
    ADEC_CHN_ATTR_S objChnAttr;

    objAdpcmAttr.enADPCMType = ADPCM_TYPE_IMA;
    objChnAttr.enType = PT_ADPCMA;
    objChnAttr.u32BufSize = 8;
    objChnAttr.enMode = ADEC_MODE_STREAM;
    objChnAttr.pValue = &objAdpcmAttr;

    iRet = HI_MPI_ADEC_CreateChn(0, &objChnAttr);
    if(iRet)
    {
        PRTMSG(MSG_ERR, "create audio playback chn1 failed: %08x\n", iRet);
        goto TTS_PLAY_STOP;
    }
}
else
{
    g_objPlaybackCtrl.APause = TRUE;// 
    sleep(1);
    SwitchAo(AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_8000);
}
#endif

g_objWorkStart.TTS = TRUE;

while( !g_objWorkStop.TTS && ReadBuf(0, TBuf, sizeof(TBuf), 'T') )
{
#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M
    HI_ADEC_SendRawData(0, &objAudioRawData);//
#endif

#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_V8 || VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M2
    memcpy(objAudioRawData.aData, TBuf, sizeof(TBuf));
    HI_MPI_AO_SendFrame(0, 0, &objAudioRawData, HI_IO_BLOCK);
#endif

    memset(TBuf, 0, sizeof(TBuf));
}

#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M
HI_ADEC_SendRawData(0, &objAudioRawData);//
#endif

#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_V8 || VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M2
memcpy(objAudioRawData.aData, TBuf, sizeof(TBuf));
HI_MPI_AO_SendFrame(0, 0, &objAudioRawData, HI_IO_BLOCK);
#endif

TTS_PLAY_STOP:

g_objWorkStop.TTS = FALSE;
WriteBuf(0, NULL, 0, 'T');//

sleep(3);//

IOSET( IOS_TRUMPPOW, IO_TRUMPPOW_OFF );//
IOSET( IOS_EARPHONESEL, IO_EARPHONESEL_ON );//
IOSET( IOS_AUDIOSEL, IO_AUDIOSEL_PHONE );//

#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M
if( !g_objCtrlStart.APlayback[0] )
{
    //
    HI_ADEC_StopCH(iAdecChn); 
    HI_ADEC_DestroyCH(iAdecChn, HI_TRUE); 
}
else
{
    g_objPlaybackCtrl.APause = FALSE;
}
#endif
#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_V8 || VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M2
if( !g_objCtrlStart.APlayback[0] )
{
    //
    HI_MPI_ADEC_DestroyChn(0);
    SwitchAo(AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_32000);
}
else
{
    SwitchAo(AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_32000);
    sleep(1);
    g_objPlaybackCtrl.APause = FALSE;
}
#endif

g_objWorkStart.TTS = FALSE;

pthread_exit(0);
}

int StartTTS()
{
if( !g_objWorkStart.TTS )
{
    PRTMSG(MSG_NOR, "Start TTS\n");

    int iRet = pthread_create(&g_pthreadTTS, NULL, PlayTTS, NULL);
    if(iRet) 
    {
        PRTMSG(MSG_ERR, "start tts failed: %08x\n", iRet);
        return -1;
    }

    sleep(1);//
    return 0;
}

return -1;
}

int StopTTS()
{
if( g_objWorkStart.TTS )
{
    PRTMSG(MSG_NOR, "Stop TTS\n");

    g_objWorkStop.TTS = TRUE;
    pthread_join(g_pthreadTTS, NULL);

    PRTMSG(MSG_NOR, "stop tts succ\n");
    return 0;
}

return -1;
}


int TTSTest(char* v_pText)
{
int iRet;

IOSET( IOS_TRUMPPOW, IO_TRUMPPOW_ON );//
IOSET( IOS_EARPHONESEL, IO_EARPHONESEL_OFF );//
IOSET( IOS_AUDIOSEL, IO_AUDIOSEL_PC );//

msleep(100);

MakeTTS(v_pText);

#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M
BYTE TBuf[960] = {0};
ADEC_CHN iAdecChn = -1;
AUDIO_RAWDATA_S objAudioRawData = {AUDIO_BIT_WIDTH_16,   AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_8, 0, 0, (short *)TBuf, (uint)sizeof(TBuf)};

iRet = HI_ADEC_CreateCH(0, AUDIO_CODEC_FORMAT_ADPCM , HI_TRUE , &iAdecChn); 
if(iRet)
{
    PRTMSG(MSG_ERR, "create audio playback chn1 failed: %08x\n", iRet);
    goto TTS_PLAY_STOP;
}

iRet = HI_ADEC_StartCH(iAdecChn, 0); 
if(iRet) 
{
    PRTMSG(MSG_ERR, "start audio playback chn1 failed: %08x\n", iRet);
    goto TTS_PLAY_STOP;
}
#endif
#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_V8 || VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M2
BYTE TBuf[960] = {0};
AUDIO_FRAME_S objAudioRawData;
objAudioRawData.enBitwidth = AUDIO_BIT_WIDTH_16;
objAudioRawData.enSoundmode = AUDIO_SOUND_MODE_MOMO;
objAudioRawData.u64TimeStamp = 0;
objAudioRawData.u32Seq = 0;
objAudioRawData.u32Len = sizeof(TBuf);

ADEC_ATTR_ADPCM_S objAdpcmAttr;
ADEC_CHN_ATTR_S objChnAttr;
objAdpcmAttr.enADPCMType = ADPCM_TYPE_IMA;
objChnAttr.enType = PT_ADPCMA;
objChnAttr.u32BufSize = 8;
objChnAttr.enMode = ADEC_MODE_STREAM;
objChnAttr.pValue = &objAdpcmAttr;

SwitchAo(AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_8000);

iRet = HI_MPI_ADEC_CreateChn(0, &objChnAttr);
if(iRet)
{
    PRTMSG(MSG_ERR, "create audio playback chn1 failed: %08x\n", iRet);
    goto TTS_PLAY_STOP;
}
#endif

while( ReadBuf(0, TBuf, sizeof(TBuf), 'T') )
{
#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M
    HI_ADEC_SendRawData(0, &objAudioRawData);//
#endif
#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_V8 || VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M2
    memcpy(objAudioRawData.aData, TBuf, sizeof(TBuf));
    HI_MPI_AO_SendFrame(0, 0, &objAudioRawData, HI_IO_BLOCK);
#endif
    memset(TBuf, 0, sizeof(TBuf));
}

#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M
HI_ADEC_SendRawData(0, &objAudioRawData);//
#endif
#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_V8 || VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M2
memcpy(objAudioRawData.aData, TBuf, sizeof(TBuf));
HI_MPI_AO_SendFrame(0, 0, &objAudioRawData, HI_IO_BLOCK);
#endif

TTS_PLAY_STOP:
WriteBuf(0, NULL, 0, 'T');//

sleep(3);//

IOSET( IOS_TRUMPPOW, IO_TRUMPPOW_OFF );//
IOSET( IOS_EARPHONESEL, IO_EARPHONESEL_ON );//
IOSET( IOS_AUDIOSEL, IO_AUDIOSEL_PHONE );//

#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M

HI_ADEC_StopCH(iAdecChn); //
HI_ADEC_DestroyCH(iAdecChn, HI_TRUE); 
#endif
#if VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_V8 || VEHICLE_TYPE == VEHICLE_M2
HI_MPI_ADEC_DestroyChn(0);//
SwitchAo(AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE_32000);
#endif
}
```

Comment: do you have any sample .irf file that we can test?

Comment: @pawan http://pan.baidu.com/wap/shareview?&shareid=3654102366&uk=3825542120&dir=%2Fautonavidata60&page=1&num=20&fsid=891585242533676&third=0

Comment: Are you saying you're going to use an irc file as vocabulary resource for tts? Never come across such scenario or you can explain more what you're going to do exactly. As I know, people tend to use AVSpeechSynthesizer.

Comment: @SanitLee I'm *pretty* sure, the irf file is **an** audio source for tts. I'm just not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @user3306356 irf file is a video file. You can try to do more search on it. Perhaps that's why you can't find info about it for tts.

Comment: @SanitLee it is used for tts, I'm sure of it. I cannot find any information, hence the question here! There's an app called "方言达人" on the app store, if you look through it's contents you will find a corresponding irf file for each of the different languages used in the app. Chinese cell phones/gps systems use irf files for tts.

Comment: @SanitLee apparently .irf files can be used the same as .dat files - .dat files are often used (esp in Windows) for TTS

Comment: I downloaded the app but don't know how to find the irf file as it's all in Chinese!

Comment: @seanxiaoxiao do you know how to do this?! found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749369/weird-behavior-of-fopen-on-ios

Comment: @SanitLee just came across this: https://github.com/onyx-intl/booxsdk/blob/master/code/src/tts/aisound/sample/ivTTSStandardAPISample.c don't know if you can make sense of it.

Comment: @SanitLee ive edited this post a lot, anything you can do with the github files?

Comment: @seanxiaoxiao help!